# I am Writing Update Function in Python to update data from MySQL server and having an error

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-workbench, face-recognition

**I am making a Face Recognition with Attendance System Project in MySQL(PYTHON)**. **There is a set of data that I am trying to update from MySQL database, and it has the following Error**:

[Error and Description Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phdtm.png)
: I am Updating data from Student Information Window

> "Due to: 1064(42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;
> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
> version for the right syntax to use near 'Div='a', Roll No='29',
> Gender='Male', DOB='8/5/2002', Email='ab@gmail.com', Teac'
> at line 1

**Here is the code of the Update Function**

```
def update_data(self):
    global conn
    if self.var_dep.get() == "Select Department" or self.var_std_name.get() == "" or self.var_std_id.get() == "":
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "All fields are Required", parent=self.root)
    else:
        try:
            Update = messagebox.askyesno("Update", "Do you want to Update Student Details", parent=self.root)
            if Update > 0:
                conn = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="08052002H@ck",
                                               database="face_recognizer")
                my_cursor = conn.cursor()
                my_cursor.execute(
                    "update student set Dep=%s, Course=%s, Year=%s, Sem=%s, Name=%s, Div=%s, Roll No=%s, Gender=%s, DOB=%s, Email=%s, Teacher Name=%s, Phone No=%s, Address=%s, Photo=%s where ID=%s",
                    (
                        self.var_dep.get(), self.var_course.get(), self.var_year.get(), self.var_semester.get(),
                        self.var_std_name.get(), self.var_div.get(), self.var_roll.get(), self.var_gender.get(),
                        self.var_dob.get(), self.var_email.get(), self.var_teacher.get(), self.var_phone.get(),
                        self.var_address.get(), self.var_radio1.get(), self.var_std_id.get()
                    enter image description here))
            else:
                if not Update:
                    return
            messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Student Details Successfully Updated", parent=self.root)
            conn.commit()
            self.fetch_data()
            conn.close()
        except Exception as es:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", f"Due to: {str(es)}", parent=self.root)
```

I am expecting when I click on the update button, it should display a success message box, and it will update data in MySQL Database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several columns (`Roll No`, `Teacher Name`, `Phone No`) with spaces in their names. Ideally, you want to avoid such identifiers in table design.

However, consider escaping the names with backticks. In fact, escape all identifiers since you also have some [MySQL reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) like `Name` and `Year`.

```py
sql = """update student 
         set `Dep`=%s, `Course`=%s, `Year`=%s, `Sem`=%s, 
             `Name`=%s, `Div`=%s, `Roll No`=%s, `Gender`=%s, 
             `DOB`=%s, `Email`=%s, `Teacher Name`=%s, 
             `Phone No`=%s, `Address`=%s, `Photo`=%s 
         where `ID`=%s"
      """
             
my_cursor.execute(sql, ...)
```